# Creating a Bat File to Clean The C#/.Net Project Folder

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, vbscript, batch-file, projects-and-solutions

I'm using "[CleanProject](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/cleanproject-remove-bin-obj-source-bindings-from-visual-studio-project-and-zip-it/)" for cleaning my project file( get rid of resharper, bin/debug files etc. )

But, it's not good because it's also deletes( #marked files );

```
-MyProjectName.sln
-MyProjectName/Properties/
-MyProjectName/obj/
-MyProjectName/bin/
-MyProjectName/MyClass/Class1.cs
-MyProjectName/MyClass/DeveloperNotes.txt  //# < CleanProject deletes the DeveloperNotes.txt
```

So, here is my question; **Can you point me an external software/batch/vbs file which I can easly edit for my needs**. A .bat - batch file will be very good because I can easly customize it. Also, I saw them in john carmack's project(Doom 3 source codes). It can be very usefull if you know how to work with it.

Thanks,

Comment: Does the standard `/clean` devenv command line parameter not meet your requirements?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But No, vs2010 clean method doesn't clean .resharper/.git folders & files. I have to send my projects with a rar file. And my several projects can't collected under one project...

Comment: Are there only specific file types you wish to spare from the delete command? like all txt/log files? Are there any distinguishing words/phrases/special characters in the files/directories you wish to save?

Comment: Yes... An example; I don't want to delete DeveloperNotes.txt which is located at the same folder with my program's "classX.cs".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use batch files, look up the FOR .. DO syntax. For example:

```
REM CLEANPROJECT.BAT
FOR /F %%F IN ('DIR /B *.dll') DO DEL %%F
FOR /F %%F IN ('DIR /B *.pdb') DO DEL %%F
```

Comment: Ok, I created a C# windows form application for that job. If I can find spare times, I will continue to develop it and make it public _ so everyone can use it in the future...  Thanks for the answer and I will mark that as an answer.